# Note 9 user cannot download our app due to compatibility issue

Tags: android, android-studio

We have a user getting a ***"Your device isn't compatible with this version"*** error when trying to download our app from the Play Store.  He is using a Note 9.

I have all this in my Manifest:

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!--all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

    <screen
        android:screenDensity="640"
        android:screenSize="normal" />


</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Our `target/compileSdkVersion` is 22 (i.e. Lollipop/5.1), and our `minSdkVersion` is 18.  I know this is all older, so I suspect this may be related to the issue, but I am needing to confirm that before proceeding on estimating the work out as such.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nuke the `<compatible-screens>` element from orbit.

Comment: Why are you even using the compatible-screens element? If you want to prevent tablets from installing the app, just blacklist them in the Device Catalog. Google Play is also going to be unlisting apps targeting anything below API 26 very soon.

Comment: This was an inherited project; I have no clue why the previous developer was using that element, but I've removed it and submitted a new version to the Store.  I did notice that after doing this, the number of supported devices went up by about 400-500.  So my hopes are high that this fixes the issue.  And yes, I fully understand about the API levels - I'm just trying to get an estimate together if that's the route we need to take (currently, updating the API level causes compile issues, so there's more work to be done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `<compatible-screens>` from manifest file and follow [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support) guide to support multiple screens.

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element):

> **Caution**: Normally, **you should not use this manifest element**. Using
>   this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your
>   application, by not allowing users to install your application if they
>   have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed.
>   You should use it only as a last resort, when the application
>   absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead
>   of using this element, you should follow the guide to [Supporting
>   Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support) to provide scalable support for multiple screens
>   using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and
>   densities.

Also change your `targetSdkVersion` to 27 or 28.

Basically you should follow below order:

```
minSdkVersion <= targetSdkVersion <= compileSdkVersion
```